# Partial sum of divisions of a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab

If there is a vector like this,

```
T = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16]
```

(the size of vector T can be flexible)

How can I get a array of **'sum of divisions'**?

For example,

```
fn(T, 5) = [ (1+2+3+4+5) , (6+7+8+9+10), (11+12+13+14+15) , 16]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider accepting one of the answer, to mark your problem as solved. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One option, which doesn't require the padding of zeros on the original array, is the use of [**`accumarray`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) and [**`ceil`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ceil.html):

```
div = 5;
out = accumarray(ceil((1:numel(T))/div).',T(:))
```

Another option using [**`cumsum`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html) and [**`diff`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) instead:

```
div = 5;
T(ceil(numel(T)/div)*div) = 0;
cs = cumsum(T)
out = diff( [0 cs(div:div:end) ] )
```

**Edit:** once the padding is done, `cumsum` and `diff` are a little overkill and one should proceed as in [**Bentoy's answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31916863/2605073).

Answer (score 5):

Another way, close to the 2nd option of [thewaywewalk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913553/1507014):

```
div = 5;
T(ceil(numel(T)/div)*div) = 0;
out = sum(reshape(T,div,[])).'; % transpose if you really want a column vector
```

Also, one one-liner solution (I prefer this one):

```
out = blockproc(T,[1 5], @(blk) sum(blk.data), 'PadPartialBlocks',true);
```

Don't forget to set the parameter 'PadPartialBlocks', this is the key of avoiding explicit padding.

Comment: You're absolutely right, after the padding step, `cumsum` and `diff` is overkill!

Answer (score 4):

There is an in-built function [`vec2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/comm/ref/vec2mat.html) in `Communications System Toolbox` to convert a vector into a 2D matrix that *cuts* off after every N elements and puts into separate rows, padding the leftover places at the end with zeros to maintain 2D size . So, after using `vec2mat`, summing all the rows would be enough to give you the desired output. Here's the implementation -

```
sum(vec2mat(T,5),2)
```

Sample run -

```
>> T = 1:16;
>> vec2mat(T,5)
ans =
     1     2     3     4     5
     6     7     8     9    10
    11    12    13    14    15
    16     0     0     0     0
>> sum(vec2mat(T,5),2)
ans =
    15
    40
    65
    16
```

Comment: requires the **Communication Systems Toolbox** though.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Yup! That's one requirement, added that info.